# Get longest strings in jsonb column

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql table with a `jsonb` column holding a lot of different data. This data needs to be moved into a DB2 database, but I need to know the max length of each individual "node" within the `jsonb` data to be sure I don't exceed the limitations of the individual DB2 column they get inserted into.

For example, `{'city':'Mesa','county':'Maricopa','mayor':'John Smith'}`

Is there a way to get the max length of each value in a `jsonb` column via SQL, resulting in something like `city: 15, county: 22, mayor: 28` short of looping over every record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a flat JSONB structure, ie. no objects and arrays exist as values, then the solution is simple.

Given the following table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE jsonbtest (data jsonb);

INSERT INTO jsonbtest (data) VALUES ('{"city":"Mesa","county":"Maricopa","mayor":"John Smith"}');
INSERT INTO jsonbtest (data) VALUES ('{"other city":"Mesa but with a longer name","county":"Maricopa","mayor":"John Smith Jr"}');
```

you can get the key-value pairs by doing

```
SELECT (jsonb_each_text(data)).* FROM jsonbtest;

    key     │   value    
────────────┼────────────
 city       │ Mesa
 mayor      │ John Smith
 county     │ Maricopa
 mayor      │ John Smith
 county     │ Maricopa
 other city │ Mesa
(6 rows)
```

Having this, getting the maximal length is a matter of a simple `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT key, max(char_length(value))
  FROM (SELECT (jsonb_each_text(data)).* FROM jsonbtest) t 
 GROUP BY key;

    key     │ max 
────────────┼─────
 city       │   4
 other city │  27
 county     │   8
 mayor      │  13
(4 rows)
```

See all this at work on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=55fa6900e3d4e8f9699f4611630df464).  See what else you cana use for processing your JSONB values in the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html).

Comment: thanks @dezso-- that's perfect!